# how to open Spotfire web player in first page?

Tags: tibco, spotfire

is there a way to open spotfire web player in first page always.
My web player link is opening analysis in different pages not on the home page.
Much appreciated

thanks

Comment: you want to open the root directory of the library each time?

Comment: please rephrase your question. it's not really clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that when you save your analysis, you save it showing the first page.

Then modify so that state isn't kept per user. Go to Edit -> Document Properties -> Library tab, and uncheck "Remember personalized view for each Web Player user":

[image: Document Properties UI - Library tab]

Answer (score 4):

Create one Document Property "OnOpenAnalysis" with DateTime:-
Write ironpyton script to that document property 
ScriptName 
Write below line in Script
**Document.ActivePageReference = Document.Pages[0]**

Add DataFunction using Open R,
use below code
input <- systime()

assign output as document property and select document property "OnOpenAnalysis"

you are done.

Comment: nice solution to update a document property without using JS! not sure if that's what @julie karen is looking for (or what she is looking for), but I'm glad I checked out your answer!