# Spotfire - javascript to trigger IronPython script to be executed on report load

Tags: javascript, spotfire

I have the follwing javascript code that it triggers an IronPython script when I load the report.

The only issue I have is that for a reason I don't know it does it (it triggers the script) a couple of times.

Can some one help me? below is the script:

```
var n=0;

$(function () {
 function executeScript() {
     if (n==0){
        n=n+1;
        now = new Date();
        if (now.getTime()-$('#hiddenBtn input').val()>10000){
            $('#hiddenBtn input').val(now.getTime());
            $('#hiddenBtn input').focus();
            $('#hiddenBtn input').blur();
        }
     }
 }
$(document).ready(function(){executeScript()}); 
strong text});
```

Please, let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with Javascript executing multiple times. Spotfire seems to instance the JS more than once, and it can cause some interesting behavior...

the best solution, in my opinion, only works if users are accessing the document via a link (as opposed to browsing the library). pass a configuration block to set a document property with a current timestamp, which would execute your IP script. this is the most solid implementation.

otherwise, you can try something like this:

```
// get a reference to a container on the page with an ID "hidden"
var $hidden = $("#hiddenBtn input");

// only continue if the container is empty
if !($hidden.text()) {
    var now = Date.now();
    $hidden.text(now)
           .focus()
           .blur();
|}
```

this is essentially the same as the code you posted, but instead of relying on the var `n`, you're counting on the input `#hiddenBtn > input` being empty. there is a caveat that you'll have to ensure this field is empty before you save the document

one addtional solution is using a Data Function to update the document property, like @user1247722 shows in his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712635/4419423

Comment: Hi niko, I tried your solucion, but did not work. I also changed a bit the script: // only continue if the container is empty
var texts = $('#hiddenBtn input').val();

    if (texts === "") {
     var now = new Date();
     $('#hiddenBtn input').val(now.getTime());
     $('#hiddenBtn input').focus();
     $('#hiddenBtn input').blur();
    }